# how to access in another class in objective -c

Tags: objective-c, function, uitextfield

I have an if statement in MessagingKeyServerResponse() in objective -c, like bellow:

```
  if (![_support_long_messages boolValue]) {

            [self showAlert];



        }
```

and in another class ContactMessagesViewController () in objective -c I have a function to limit my textfield .

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 1000) ? NO : YES;
}
```

what i am trying to do is: in my if statement I would like to add function above to limit in my if statement the characters of textfield to 160 any help appreciate .

Comment: `if (textView.text.length > 160) {` ?

Comment: You mean to write this inside my if statement? but textView is in another class, how can I access to textview?

Comment: Well, you have to pass the text there somehow, so use that text.

Comment: Actually the problem is how to pass the text. :)

Comment: You need to at least show how `MessagingKeyServerResponse` is defined and how it gets called. You've shown a method which takes a `UITextView *` as a parameter, therefore you understand about parameter passing making your comment "the problem is how to pass the text" in need of further explanation.

Comment: Thanks CRD, it is long coding, if I can pass the bool value in another class it can solve my problem also.